# How to Convert object result model to a custom view model in asp .net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net-entity-data-model

I had done a project of using stored procedure to display join table values using entity framework.
I had done all the basic procedure and while calling it from my model it successfully return the object result,

Now my problem is I cannot able to convert that result model from stored procedure which is of complex return type to my view model.
Can some one help me in solving it.

I had attached my project workings below,

This is the auto generated context by ADO .net Entity model

[image]

Edit function in model browser function imports

[image]

Display result which is auto generated.

[image]

This is what i'm trying to do

[image]

And this is the error I'm getting

[image]

This is how my view model consist of

[image]

Stored procedure query (Mysql)

[image]

Comment: you have to provide mapping for your `ViewModel` in the `.Select()` like:`var query = objEmployee.sp_display().Select(s=>new ViewModel{employees=new employee{//add the mapping properties here},employee_detail = new employee_detail{//add the mapping properties here}}).ToList()`.

Comment: @vikscool will you show me a sample example for that add mapping properties location, I have name and department in employee table and address and mobile in employee details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by OP the schema of `employee` and `employee_details` is something like:

```
public class employee
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Department {get;set;}
}

public class employee_details
{
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string Mobile {get;set;}
}
```

So, after applying the mapping your code would look something like:

```
var query = objEmployee.sp_display().Select(s=> new ViewModel{
employees = new employee{
 Name = s.Name //change the s.Name to the property name coming from your SP(if different)
 Department = s.Department
},
employee_detail = new employee_detail{
  Address = s.Address,
  Mobile = s.Mobile
}}).ToList()
```

Or Better just remove the `query` object and use the `listEmployeeList` as this list itself is also referencing the `ViewModel` so the `query` object is un-necessary(*unless you want to do some other filtration on it*)  :

```
listEmployeeList = // the above code with .ToList();
```

Comment: As I displayed above in the 3rd image there are no properties written were the stored procedure return the value. Since it is auto-generated any future changes will overwrite if we define the properties manually, even though I defined it manually it assigning the number of index list of "listEmployeeList" but it dosen't store any value, It just displays a null value. Am I missing any mapping during the model creation?

Comment: It would display null as you have no properties defined in the `sp_display_result` class. If the columns can change from the `Procedure` then the `ViewModel` class as well have to change. So, it is better to provide mapping properties in the `sp_display_result` class. Else use a `DataTable` to capture the data and then convert it to `json` and pass it to client/handle in business logi to support mapping.

Comment: Since there is no input parameter in the procedure, How to map with sp_display_result.?Is there any way to map.